# lapply, glm, and speedglm inside a function: argument "data" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, lapply, glm, speedglm

I am using `mtcars` data to show my problem. The following code works fine with `glm`. It generates new models by adding each variable in the `vlist` to the model of `glm(vs ~ mpg, family = binomial(), data = mtcars`.

```
check_glm <- function(crude, vlist, data, ...){
  a <- glm(crude, data = data, family = binomial())
  lapply(vlist, function(x) update(a, as.formula(paste0(". ~ . +", x))))
}
check_glm(crude = "vs ~ mpg", vlist = c("am", "hp"), data = mtcars)
```

However, when I replaced `glm` with `speedglm`,

```
library(speedglm)
check_speedglm <- function(crude, vlist, data, ...){
  a <- speedglm(crude, data = data, family = binomial())
  lapply(vlist, function(x) update(a, as.formula(paste0(". ~ . +", x))))
}
check_speedglm(crude = "vs ~ mpg", vlist = c("am", "hp"), data = mtcars)
```

I got:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = vs ~ mpg + am, data = data,
>   drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : argument "data" is missing, with no
>   default.

I think the problem is in the `lapply` line but I could not work out a solution. Any suggestions to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you are mixing up package methods that may not be compatible with each other. Though they share same name, both of these methods are from different packages so different authors for different purposes and output different objects (`glm` class vs. `speedglm` class which may be S3 vs S4 objects).

Specifically, the `glm` method is part of R's standard library in `stats` package, which works with its related `stats` method, `update`.

Per [`update`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/update) docs,

> `update` will update and (by default) re-fit a model. It does this by extracting the call stored in the object, updating the call and (by default) evaluating that call.

Main argument:

> **object, x**: An existing fit from a model function such as `lm`, `glm` and many others

Therefore, if `speedglm` stores the call to capture formula, data, and others args and resembles the return object structure as `glm` (which inherits from `lm` class), then `update` would work.

---

To resolve, consider doing what `update` does by dynamically building `formula` with iterative model calls using `lapply`. This would work in both methods, since each uses the `formula` object.

```
library(speedglm) 

check_speedglm <- function(crude, vlist, data, ...){ 
   lapply(seq_along(vlist), function(i)
       speedglm(as.formula(paste(crude, "+", paste(vlist[1:i], collapse=" + "))), 
                data = data, family = binomial()) 
   )
} 

check_speedglm(crude = "vs ~ mpg", vlist = c("am", "hp"), data = mtcars)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! It is of great help for my work. The `system time` was reduced from 581.94 seconds with `glm` to 13.21 seconds with `speedglm`.

Comment: Interesting! Great to hear and glad I could help!